# Flow - pause/resume flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

In RxJava there is the `valve` operator that allows to pause (and buffer) a flow and resumes the flow again (and also emit the buffered values as soon as it's resumed). It's part of the rx java extensions (https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions/blob/3.x/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/rxjava3/operators/FlowableValve.java).

Is there something like this for kotlin flows?

My use case is that I want to observe a flow inside an activity and never lose an event (like I would do it with `LiveData` e.g. which stops observing data if the activity is paused). So while the activity is paused I want the flow to buffer observed values until the activity is resumed and emit them all as soon as the activity is resumed.

So while the activity is created (until it is destroyed) I want to observe the flow BUT I only want to emit values while the activity is active and buffer the values while it is not active (but still created) until it gets active again.

Is there something to solve this or has anyone ever written something to solve this?

Comment: I hope this article would help you to learn of repeatOnLifecycle https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `Lifecycle.launchWhenX` and a `SharedFlow` should do the trick. Here's a simple example using a flow that emits a number every second.

```
// In your ViewModel
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val numbers = flow {
        var counter = 0
        while (true) {
            emit(counter++)
            delay(1_000L)
        }
    }
        .shareIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.Lazily
        )
}
```

```
// In your Fragment.onViewCreated()
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    viewModel.numbers
        .collect { number ->
            Log.d("asdf", "number: $number")
        }
}
```

This works because `Lifecycle.launchWhenStarted` pauses the coroutine when the `Lifecycle` enters a stopped state, rather than cancels it. When your `Lifecycle` comes back to a started state after pausing, it'll collect everything that happened while in the stopped state.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is ugly solution but it works fine for me:

```
fun main() {
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<String>(extraBufferCapacity = 50, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
    val isOpened = AtomicBoolean()

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    GlobalScope.launch(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
        flow
            .transform { value ->
                while (isOpened.get().not()) { }
                emit(value)
            }
            .collect {
                println("${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}: $it")
            }
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    flow.tryEmit("First")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    isOpened.set(true)
    flow.tryEmit("Second")
    isOpened.set(false)
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    isOpened.set(true)
    flow.tryEmit("Third")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
}
```

Result:
[image: code execution result]

So you can set isOpened to false when your activity lifecycle paused and to true when resumed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted`
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow